# 2 cross pattern not going right on Front wheel build

Tags: spokes, wheel-building

I need to make 2 cross spoke pattern (because lack of proper length spokes) for front wheel, i am however having some problem - green spokes stick out trough the rim ~4-5mm longer than blue spokes.

Blue spokes angle is -60 degree, green spoke angle is is +20 degree from the hub (compared to radial lacing).

Is this 2 cross pattern diagram wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagram is fine but you might have incorrect length spokes or the spoking on the other side of the wheel isn't aligned properly.

Comment: Rememember to free your nipples from the rim, they can get stuck on the edge of the hole on some rims.

Comment: Turning my attention to the left edge of the wheel, I see that the joint and surrounding area are in rough shape. This thing looks like junk; is this for wheel building practice, or just emotional value attached to the wheel, or are you going to ride this? Is there going to be a rim brake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top flange spokes in the picture are laced right, but the bottom is not. You need to make each pair of pushing and pulling spokes that follow each other coming from the opposite side flanges take consecutive holes in the rim. Take all the nipples off the bottom side, put the one I've marked in the hole I'm calling *A*, and then move all the other spokes on that flange the same number of holes down from where they were and it will be right.

Another way of thinking about why the angles are assyemmtrical as you describe is that the hub hasn't been able to have its "twist" done such that they can be symmetrical.

[image]

Comment: indeed was the problemI don't know how that happened must have been very tired yesterday. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You have the spokes misaligned - the spokes on the far side of the wheel as seen in the picture cross the spokes on the other side of the wheel when they shouldn't.

Look at the spoke at the 7 o'clock position in the image - the one that's brightly reflecting. Trace it back to the hub. It goes to the far side of the hub.

Now, at the rim, move one spoke to the right towards the 6 o'clock position.  Trace that spoke back to the hub.  It goes to the near side of the hub in the picture.

See how it crosses over the first spoke?

It shouldn't cross like that - it should be running to the spoke hole to the ***left*** of the brightly-reflecting spoke at the 7 o'clock position, not to the hole to the right of that spoke like it does.

All the spokes on that side of the wheel need to be moved 2 spoke holes clockwise as picture.

At least that will be closer - you may be further off than that as it's hard to tell from the posted image.

Pick a spoke on one side of the hub.  Move to the other side of the hub.  Directly opposite the spoke you picked should be between two spoke holes.  Move to the hole in the direction the spoke on the other side "points".  For most symmetrical lacing schemes, the spoke in that hole should run to next hole in the rim past the spoke on the other side.